AIOGRAM 3: How to resume bot after internet disconnecting
I have problem with my bot on Aiogram3. My bot stop working after the internet disappeared. Usually, when the Internet appears, the bot does not work. I wrote a script that should ensure that the bot is launched.
def check_process(process_name):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
        if proc.info['name'] == process_name:
            return True
    return False

def main():
    process_name = "MarriageGames.exe"
    while True:
        try:
            if check_process(process_name):
                print(f"The process {process_name} is running.")
            else:
                print(f"The process {process_name} is not running.")
                subprocess.Popen([process_name])
            time.sleep(5)
        except:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

There is script, that run bot:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            from handlers import *
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
            asyncio.run(main())
        except:
            time.sleep(5)

I had an assumption that if I put the bot launch in While True, the bot will work even after the internet is unstable.
Please tell me if you know of a way to ensure that the bot can resume its work with unstable Internet? And is it possible to send a message "Bot run again" to the admin via his chat id?

You can use request like this:
import requests
import time

def check_network():
    try:
        requests.get('https://www.google.com', timeout=5)  # Try to connect to Google
        return True  # If successful, return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return False  # If connection error occurs, return False

def network_connection():
    network_status = check_network()  # Initial network status
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)  # Check every 5 seconds
        new_network_status = check_network() # Check network status again
        if new_network_status != network_status:  # If there's a change in status
            if new_network_status:
                #code for the bot is up again

            network_status = new_network_status  # Update network status

if __name__ == "__main__":
    network_connection()

Even though i highly recomend hosting your code on a cloud server to limit the damage.
I hope this helps
